# lags and rolling window in Azure AutoML Time series forecasting

Tags: time-series, azure-ml, automl

I'm following [this tutorial to try Machine Learning AutoML Forecasting.](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/automated-machine-learning/forecasting-energy-demand/auto-ml-forecasting-energy-demand.ipynb)

In the several parameters we can submit to the AutoML experiment, we have these ones:

1. target_logs;
2. target_rolling_window_size;

Can you explain with an example how the several forecasting algorithms works when these two parameters are set?

Thank you

> ```
> automl_advanced_settings = {
>     'time_column_name': time_column_name,
>     'max_horizon': max_horizon,
>     'target_lags': 12,
>     'target_rolling_window_size': 4,
> }
> automl_config = AutoMLConfig(task='forecasting',                             
>                              primary_metric='normalized_root_mean_squared_error',                  
>
>                              experiment_timeout_hours=0.3,
>                              training_data=train,
>                              label_column_name=target_column_name,
>                              compute_target=compute_target,
>                              enable_early_stopping = True,
>                              n_cross_validations=3,                             
>                              verbosity=logging.INFO,
>                             **automl_advanced_settings)
> ```